# how to send string through mvc form parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this form-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveVideo", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-upload", @Class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return tags()", genres = "return genres()" }))
{
}
```

where on form submit I will need to send strings seperated by comma.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function genres() {
        var genres = $('#input-genreautocomplete').val();
        return genres;
    }

    function tags() {
        var tags = $('#input-tagautocomplete').val();
        return tags;
    </script>
```

Now as an example genre would be like- `23,15,16,22,11` as same as tags is. It return me string seperated by comma.

Now I want to use these strings in my method `SaveVideo` . But I can't get these strings working as parameters. How Do I send these strings on method?

**Autocompletes working like this-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('#input-tagautocomplete').tagsinput({
            itemValue: 'Id',
            itemText: 'TagName',
            typeahead: {
                source: function (term, process) {
                    items = [];
                    map = {};
                    idofitem = [];
                    var url = "@Url.Content("~/Upload/GetTagNames/")";
                    return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            map[item] = item;
                            items.push(item.TagName);

                        });
                        return (items);
                    });
                },
                updater: function (item) {
                    var selected = map[item].Id;
                    $('#tag-value').val(selected);
                    return item;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where updater is not working, though it's bootstrap's typeahead's extension.

Comment: Send it through $.ajax(https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @karthik, I have requirement of sending it through parameters only.

Comment: Can you show us where the `#input-genreautocomplete` and `#input-tagautocomplete` elements are created?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a bit confused. Action parameters don't need to be specified in the `BeginForm()` helper. In fact, I don't think doing so makes any sense. Firstly, these inputs should be inside your form if they're not already:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveVideo", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-upload", @Class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="text" id="input-tagautocomplete" name="tags" />
    <input type="text" id="input-genreautocomplete" name="genres" />
}
```

You could also create these using an HTML helper. The important thing is that they have a value specified for their `name` attribute.

Then you can just add parameters to your action method to match these names:

```
public ActionResult SaveVideo(string tags, string genres)
{
     // do whatever you want with tags and genres
}
```